# Force maven to always fetch artifacts from target folder

Tags: maven

#### Circumstances

It would be nice to split long running build jobs, espescially in multi module projects.

1. Compile everything `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean package`
2. Execute unit tests on each module `mvn surefire:test`
3. Execute integrations tests `ant and stuff`
4. Publish artifacts to a remote repository `mvn my.own.tools:publish-plugin:publish`
5. Execute post build steps (Tagging, etc) `build server stuff`

In some build environments, like Atlassian Bamboo, each step will be likely executed on another build agent as the previous one. They can even have their own local repository each. However, it is possible to copy all the files of the working directory to that of a subsequent stage.

#### Observation

Maven uses the contents of the `target` folders before it makes a lookup into the local repository or a remote repository. This is true when the contents of the target directories are created by a previous `phase` during a specific run.

Example: `mvn clean install surefire:test`

If a test has dependencies, maven will look at first in the target directories which have been created during the `compile phase`.

If the command is split into two, it seems that maven does not recognize the `target` folders at all.

Example: `mvn clean install; mvn surefire:test`

Now maven loads all the dependencies from the local repository or, if they are not there, from a remote repository.

#### Problem(s)

- During step 2 maven ignores the contents inside the target foldera, which have been created during step 1.
- Step 2 runs on a different build server, than step 1. However, the whole file structure (including the target folders) from step 1 have been copied into the working directory from step 2. The artifacts which the tests depend on, are not taken out of those directories. Since each build server has it's own local repository, they are not found and on the remote repository they have never been uploaded.
- Any idea of making our whole beast more modular and split up the project is unfortunately no possiblity

#### Question

How can maven be forced to load dependencies out of existing target folders of a multi module project under any circumstances? I understand that maven is not aware of those folders in step 2 since they are not created during that maven run. But how can I force maven to look if those folders exists?

#### More elaborted problem ;-)

Our "Publish-Plugin" in step 4 seems to work mostly fine and uploads the artifacts out of the target folders. The project iformation is gathered inside the Mojo by usual maven properties. But there are some zip files created during step 1 by the `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin`. Those zip files are not found, although they are residing inside the target folder. Now maven tries to download them, what is funny, because it does that to have them in hand for a upload.

Comment: I don't really understand why you want to run the different steps on different build agents? Why not run them all on one build agent?

Comment: The are distributed by bamboo and I don't want to dedicate one agent for a build configuration. It's the way baboo works and unfortunately you cannot force it to use the same agent for stage n+x as for stage n.

Comment: Then it is maybe a bad idea to split the build in the first place. You can attach everything to the maven lifecycle. Then one `mvn clean deploy` will do all the steps you want to do.

Comment: In general it's a good idea to detect compile failures before spending much time for all the testing. Beside that it has some advantages if you don't publish artifacts before a build fails. I appreciate your interest, but we try such things on purpose ;-)

Comment: I am just trying to understand the circumstances. My humble opinion is that your approach will be very difficult to implement. The only approach that comes to my mind would be to define a local repository for the build configuration that is used on all agents.

Comment: Yeah, that's the default setting. But then, when you build multiple feature branches in parallel, the maven tasks try to write meta data at the same time into that single repository. To prevent that, different build server developers com around with repository isolation, where each build process has it's own repository. Each solution has it's caveats :(

Comment: Sorry to be misleading: I meant that each process needs its own repository (parallel use of the same repository should be avoided), but one could coordinate the repository in a way that the subsequent steps you mentioned above always use the same repository. I.e. you could create a random number at the beginning of the build and use that to choose/define  a local repository that you use in each step.

Comment: That's indeed a good idea. First i thought about assigning previously existing repositories. But then there is another problem: Step 1 and 4 take Repo 1. Between those steps, another build agent has used Repo 1. Then this repo is corrupted. Completely dynamically repos, as you mentioned, could be a thing, which are set up for each build, but then you would always have an empty repo and we are fetching lots and lots of libraries. Performance is also an issue :-D

Comment: You could fetch a repo and put some kind of lock (e.g. a file) in it. You remove the lock after the build.